# QGIS Polygon features split by area

Tags: python, qgis

I have a shape file with **10,000 polygon** features in **QGIS**

I want each polygon to be splitted into multiple polygons features (**partitioning whole polygon area**) using some attribute value say NoOfPartions.

I am using QGIS for same but doesn't seem any way to do so for all features.

Manually clipping is not feasible due to large no of features.

Any possible way to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am pretty sure you will get an answer faster if you ask here http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks Christian for suggestion.
I have posted it there too now

Comment: Maybe you can try with this experimental plugin "Shapefile Splitter" http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapefile_splitter/

Comment: Is this different from Split By Attribute operation? Could not find this plugin in QGIS tool Plugin repo.

Comment: you need activate "experimental plugins" option. https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html

Comment: its already enabled.
I can see various other experimental plugins (QGIS 2.14)

Comment: then download the plugin from this site http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapefile_splitter/version/0.1.2/ and unzip in your qgis plugins folder ,read it http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline